# Why is the macroscopic Heat capacity related to the standard deviation of microscopic energy fluctuations?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature

In one of the problems in my textbook (Schroeder Intro to Thermal Physics), it is shown that within the canonical ensemble, the standard deviation of the energy fluctuations for a single microscopic system within the ensemble (denoted $\sigma_E$), is related to the macroscopic heat capacity of the entire system (All atoms/subsystems that make up the thermodynamics system) by the following formula
$$\sigma_E =kT\frac{\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{k}}$$
where $C$ is the Heat capacity of the macroscopic system. This seems to be a very profound result. Is there any way to understand why this is the case? I can't seem to figure out why a greater amount of thermal fluctuations per particle ($\sigma_E$) should imply a larger heat capacity on the macroscopic level. Is there any way to visualize this?

Comment: We can derive this by expressing both $\sigma_E$ and $C$ in terms of derivatives of the partition function with respect to $\beta=1/kT$, as shown [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Statistical_Thermodynamics_(Jeschke)/04%3A_Classical_Ensembles/4.03%3A_Canonical_Ensemble). Are you asking for a derivation, or are you asking for intuition? (The former should be the foundation for the latter.)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Thanks for the response. I know how to derive the equation and agree that the derivation must be the foundation of intuition. I am asking how to intuit the fact that increased energy fluctuations correspond to an increased heat capacity. For example, atoms that have a large amount of degrees of freedom (translational+ rotational +perhaps a few vibrational etc)  have a higher heat capacity than those that have few degrees of freedom. This is because the former can store more energy than the later. Is there a similar explanation for the correspondence between $\sigma_E$ and $C_v$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks for intuition. The equation shown in the question can be derived from the fact that $\sigma_E^2$ and $C$ can both be expressed in terms of derivatives of the partition function with respect to $\beta=1/kT$, as shown [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Statistical_Thermodynamics_(Jeschke)/04%3A_Classical_Ensembles/4.03%3A_Canonical_Ensemble). We can extract some intuition from that derivation.

In the canonical ensemble, the probability of a state with energy $E$ is proportional to $e^{-E/kT}$. The partition function can be written either as a sum over states,
$$
 Z = \sum_n e^{-E_n/kT},
\tag{1}
$$
or as a sum over energies,
$$
 Z = \sum_E \rho(E) e^{-E/kT}
\tag{2}
$$
where $\rho(E)$ is the density of states with energy $E$. In a comment, you described some prior intuition about heat capacity:

> atoms that have a large amount of degrees of freedom (translational+ rotational +perhaps a few vibrational etc) have a higher heat capacity than those that have few degrees of freedom. This is because the former can store more energy than the later.

To get that intuition from (2), use the fact that for each of those types of degree of freedom (translational, rotational, vibrational), the number of such states in an energy-shell of given width $dE$ is an increasing function of the energy $E$. Consequently, the more different types of degrees of freedom the system has, the more rapidly $\rho(E)$ grows as a function of $E$. **That's the key.** A system with more degrees of freedom has larger-magnitude derivatives of the partition function with respect to $\beta=1/kT$, for any given value of $T$. Since $\sigma_E^2$ and $C$ are both expressed in terms of the first- and second-derivatives of the partition function with respect to $\beta$, this explains intuitively why both of them have the same dependence on the number of degrees of freedom. In particular, it explains intuitively why both of them are larger (for a given $T$) in systems with more degrees of freedom.

Here's a little more detail about the intuition behind $\sigma_E^2$. Consider the summand in (2). We can think of $\sigma_E$ as the width of the peak in the graph of $\rho(E)e^{-E/kT}$ as a function of $E$. If we make $\rho(E)$ grow more rapidly, we shift the peak to a larger value of $E$, and that also makes the peak wider because $e^{-E/kT}$ doesn't decrease as rapidly for larger values of $E$ (it's derivative approaches zero as $E\to \infty$). That's why increasing the number of degrees of freedom makes $\sigma_E^2$ larger, for given value of $T$.

The intuition is tied to the mathematical form of the canonical ensemble (1)-(2). That's unavoidable, because we can contrive different ensembles in which $\sigma_E^2$ and $C$ are not be related to each other as shown in the question. Then again, since the canonical ensemble is essentially a consequence of the microcanonical ensemble (which is the least-presumptuous ensemble), we don't normally need to consider other ensembles, so the relationship shown in the question is relatively robust.

Comment: This is one of the best responses I've seen on this site. Thanks so much! Just one thing before I accept your answer. You state "Since $\sigma_E$and $C$ are both expressed in terms of the first- and second-derivatives of the partition function with respect to E". How do we go about expressing these as first and second derivative of $Z$ with respect to E? Shouldn't it be with respect to T or $\beta$?

Comment: @SalahTheGoat Thank you for the kind words! And you're right about the derivatives. I meant with respect to $\beta=1/kT$, like the first paragraph said. I updated the answer to fix that silly mistake. Well, I call it "silly" because I know what I meant, but mistakes like that can really be frustrating to students who are reading the answer and don't know it's just a mistake, so I'm very glad you pointed it out so I could fix it. Thanks!